# ¿Cómo validar cuando el parámetro esta vacío?

Tags: phalcon

tengo un api rest en la cual es posible que el parametro "isproperty" puede venir vacio o en su defecto 1 o 0.

```
public function searchproperty($isproperty)
    {
        if($isproperty == 0){
            return parent::search();
        }else if($isproperty == 1){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->modelClass WHERE is_property = 1";
            $data = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql)->execute();

            $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
            $this->response->setJsonContent($data);
            return $this->response->send();
        }

    }
```

no se como validar esta parte ya que si el parametro no tiene nada me marca un error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar `empty`, devuelve `true` si una variable esta vacia. Espero te sirva:

```
public function searchproperty($isproperty)
    {
        if(!empty($isproperty)){   // TE AGREGUE ESTA LINEA, si isproperty NO esta vacia
            if($isproperty == 0){
                return parent::search();
            }else if($isproperty == 1){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->modelClass WHERE is_property = 1";
                $data = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql)->execute();

                $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
                $this->response->setJsonContent($data);
                return $this->response->send();
            }

         }else{ // Y TAMBIEN AGREGUE ESTAS TRES LINEAS
                  echo 'esto se imprimirá si la variable está vacia';
                 }


    }
```

Comment: Hay alguna alternativa para usarla cuando no llegue el parametro? es decir que no se envíe "$isproperty"

Comment: Si, con isset() podes verificar si una variable está o no definida.

Comment: Acá tenes algunos ejemplos https://www.anerbarrena.com/php-isset-4876/

Comment: por ejemplo puede llegar de las siguientes formas **http://dev.clever-api-core.local/propiedad/search/** o **http://dev.clever-api-core.local/propiedad/search/1** pero en el primer caso me marca un error 404

Comment: Creo que no te estoy llegando a entender del todo, y ya me tengo que ir. Te diria que concatenes /0 a la direccion, en return parent::search().'/0'; pero creo que no te entendi bien. Disculpa si no pude ayudarte, espero alguien lo haga pronto.

Comment: De cualquier forma la información fue util.